# Configure a lightweight DNS server to return same IP for all domains in LAN and on Windows

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, lightweight

As i mentioned in the post title i want to config a temperately server in local network to just displays a local website (or webpage) to all of users which are connected to the WiFi. (Because the 99 percent of users are in cellphones i need all domain redirection not just "Google" and so)

This is not duplicated question as the similar questions was in Linux.

Is it (Using the DNS) the best answer to achiving this purpose or there is another better way.

Is it possible with these lightweight kind of DNS servers [maraDNS](http://maradns.samiam.org/) , ... ?

And how to config it.

Comment: I think what you'd really be after is a transparent proxy, something that can get inline and apply optimisation techniques. There are plenty of commercial options, such as from Exinda and others (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exinda lists a bunch of similar companies).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accelerator has a bunch of other similar products too, although possibly aimed at different spaces. You might elaborate on your "99 percent of users are in cellphones"...

Comment: I guess using transparent-proxy needs more work to config.

Comment: Thanks @CameronKerr, I guess using transparent-proxy needs more work to config. redirecting all TCP requests on windows to a special port. configuring the proxy server to mirror the requests and just response a websites data to clients all HTTP requests. (The website contains many parts as: main page, child pages, picture & maybe more parts, and the request should be handle by web server). Am i wrong?

Comment: You could write a PowerShell listener that responds to every request with the same DNS response. [Here's one for HTTP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41638/418-im-a-teapot/41665#41665), just modify it for your needs.

Comment: @user2320464 This is so interesting. Maybe its better to me to develop a simple custom DNS server to do this job. Do you have any source code or idea how to implement it? I don't know anything about DNS requests type formats and what should be look like the responses related to that request. Thank you for your helps.